# Why <TextInput> cannot be focused when inside an absolute positioned parent container <View> in React Native?

Tags: react-native, focus, css-position, textinput

I have a `TextInput` component that is located inside a `View` with a style setting of `position: "absolute"`:

```
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('Test');
return (
   <View style={{position: "absolute"}}>
      <TextInput
         autoFocus={true}
         value={searchTerm}
         onChangeText={text => setSearchTerm(text)}
      />
   </View>
)
```

When this style is set, I cannot focus or perform any interaction with the `TextInput` (including `autoFocus={true}`) even though I can see the input field and default text (`Test`). Once I remove the absolute positioning I am able to work with the `TextInput` as usual.

What is the reason for this behavior? (using Android)

Comment: For me it was because the actual text input wasn't inside the bounding box of the view that the absolutely positioned view was in. Very stupid mechanic.

Answer (score 0):

you should add `zIndex:400` or some high number it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining why this may solve the OP's problem.

Comment: zIndex:400 or some high number works because  it will make sure the TextInput tag is on top layer of the App, and am guessing focusing on TextInput only works in that case

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this problem is explained here: [Long-press to select and press to move cursor doesn't work on position: 'absolute' TextInput outside parent bounds on Android](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/37181)

The solution is that you likely need to change the parent of the `position: 'absolute'` view so that its bounds contain the position-absolute view. That parent isn't in your code sample, so the parent view is in another component.